# Get the count of an object

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a view object, the result of the following query:

```
SELECT TEACHER_ID_FK, 
       MATERIAL_ID_FK, 
       CREATION_DATE, 
       VALID_BEFORE 
FROM TEACHER_MATERIAL;
```

In my application module I have this line of code to get hold of the view object.

```
TeachMaterVVOImpl voTeachMater = (TeachMaterVVOImpl)this.getTeachMaterVVO1();
```

Now I got a `materialId(of type MATERIAL_ID_FK)` in my hand.

How to get the number of count of this materialId from this view object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in the following way:

1. Get the *View Object*
2. Iterate over it in a loop
3. Get the material *ID*s
4. Get the *count* of each material *ID*
5. Group them by the *count* and *ID* in a map
6. Get the count from the map by the *ID* at hand

And it worked super fine.

Comment: I dont have a bind variable the whole page is defined as unbounded definition, so no chance in aquirinf one sided id sorting with gestEstimatedRowCount as you mentioned beforehand . . .

Answer (score 0):

Which jdev version do you use?
What do you have in mind with the count? 
Show it on a page?
Or do you need it elsewhere?

In general you should define a view criteria with the materialId as bind parameter. Then it depends on your use case what you do with the view criteria. You can implement a method in the vo and apply the view Curtis with the parameter via this method out you can add a specialized vo which has the view criteria set as default.

Timo

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I know what view criteria is and that it is a where clause (doesn't work here!), I need the count of a specific value of a column!

Comment: Well, you are wrong here. However,  as you did not answer one of my questions it's hard to give an advise. Once you have set the view criteria you get the count by calling getEstimatedRowCount()  Which is a select count(1) from (your_query_with_parameter_in_view Criteria)

Comment: And what should be my view criteria query?